# Mongodb gives error with nested schema

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently learning Mean Stack from Getting Mean textbook. I ran into this issue when I use subdocuments on `locationSchema`. It must be something related to `ref` property. How do I manage to fix this?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// reviewSchema
var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   author: String,
});
var openingTimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   days: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   }
});
// We use openingTimeSchema as a subdocument here
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: {
      Type: String,
      required: true
   },

   openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema],
   reviews: [reviewSchema]
});

// Build Mongose Schema to models
mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```

`Error`:

```
TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `name.required`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
    at Function.Schema.interpretAsType (loc8r/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:592:11)
    at Schema.path (loc8r/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:499:29)
    at Schema.add (loc8r/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:389:12)
    at Schema.add (loc8r/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:384:14)
    at new Schema (loc8r/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:92:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (loc8r/app_server/models/locations.js:30:22)
```

Comment: In your definition of `name`, it should be `type: String`, not `Type: string`.

Comment: Wow typo. :o Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Typo :o*** on `name` property:

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: {
      Type: String,
      required: true
   },

   openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema],
   reviews: [reviewSchema]
});
```

It should be:

```
name: {
   type: String,
   required: true
},
```